# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'NSNumber' operands -- swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, nsnumber

Help. I just converted to swift 3 and am getting errors when I try to add two NSNumbers together i.e.:

```
var foodPrice: NSNumber!
var priceSum: NSNumber!
foodPrice = 6.79
priceSum = 11.89
var totalSum = NSNumber(foodPrice + priceSum) // <-- error here
```

OR

```
var totalSum = (foodPrice + priceSum) as NSNumber // <-- still error here
```

Doesn't matter how I change totalSum I can't get away from this error. Please help. This is my official SOS. Dazed and confused here. How do I make this work?

Comment: There is no `+` operator which takes `NSNumber` operands.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write your own `+` override for `NSNumber`?

```
func + (lhs: NSNumber, rhs: NSNumber) -> NSNumber {
    return NSNumber(value: lhs.floatValue + rhs.floatValue)
}

var foodPrice: NSNumber = 6.79
var priceSum: NSNumber  = 11.89

var totalSum = foodPrice + priceSum // 18.68
```

I use floats here but you can use any type you need.

Comment: The problem that I see is: What is *"any type you need"*? The application might use NSNumbers containing (for example) Float, Double, and (U)Int64 at different places. No matter which representation you use in your `+` operator, it won't work correctly in all cases.

Comment: @MartinR Your right, this isn't really a reusable approach.  Any suggestions how to improve this function (if any)?  Or just treat each NSNumber on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foodPrice: NSNumber!
var priceSum: NSNumber!
foodPrice = 6.79
priceSum = 11.89
var totalSum = NSNumber(double: foodPrice.doubleValue + priceSum.doubleValue)
```

Try this out..!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var totalSum = NSNumber(value: foodPrice.doubleValue + priceSum.doubleValue)
```